# How to make table column with dynamic width

Tags: html, css

I have a table with dynamic number of columns.
If table width increases more than 100%, then column width should be minimum width defined in CSS. Otherwise column width should be fit to the content.

How can I do it?

```
<style>
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: auto;
}
td {
    min-wdith: 250px;
}
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Col 1
        </td>
        <td>
            Col 2
        </td>
        <td>
            Col 3
        </td>
        <td>
            Col 4
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You have a typo : ``min-wdith`` instead of ``min-width``. I am not sure if what you wish for is possible using only CSS, but specifying a min-width will cause for the cells to be larger than your content if it is short, no matter the size of the table. Also, if you have many columns (let's say eight), your table would be larger than an HD screen anyway (8 x 250 px = 2000 px, which is greater than 1920 px).

Comment: It's working for large number of column, but not for the small column. Say If I have only one cloumn, then this column width becomes 100% of table.

Comment: If you force a min-width on all your columns, your table will be wider than your screen if you have too many columns. This was my point.

Also, I would like to understand, why is it important to have a minimal width when the "fit content" mode does not fit the screen? Specifying a (max-)width to the table and no width to the td would already cause the browser to calculate optimal width for each column, and the table would not overflow.

Answer (score 5):

Simple solution: give `width: 100%;` to table.

```css
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid;
    margin-top:20px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    min-width: 250px;
    border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Col 1
        </td>
        <td>
            Col 2
        </td>
        <td>
            Col 3
        </td>
        <td>
            Col 4
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Col 1
        </td>
        <td>
            Col 2
        </td>
        
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I want the width fit to the content.

Comment: As i know width fit to content and `min-width` both will not possible using css.

Comment: I also dont know how to do it with JS.

Comment: If you remove the min-width on ``td``, the columns will automatically adjust according to the content of each. Because you have specified a ``width`` on the table, it will not go further than the screen. No minimal width will be applied, so that columns with larger contents will still have a higher weight.

Comment: @Chop Yes i know but OP require `min-width` so.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot hope to both have a min-width and fit smaller contents.